# Powershell Cyrillic input encoding through node js

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, powershell, encoding

I trying to make Cyrillic text-to-speech node js module.

I using [node-powershell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell) to run .NET TTS commands. And it works fine with Latin symbols but does not react on any Cyrillic symbols.

**However if I input command directly to the Powershell console - it works fine with both cyrillic and latin symbols.** 
[image]

So I made a disition that problem point is node.js output encoding.

Node.js script:

```
var sayWin = (text) => {
  var Shell = require('node-powershell');
  var shell = new Shell({
    inputEncoding: 'binary' //tried different endcoding
  });
  shell.addCommand('Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech');
  shell.addCommand('$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer');
  shell.addCommand('$speak.Speak("' + text + '")');
  shell.on('output', data => {
    console.log("data", data);
  });
  return shell.invoke();
}

sayWin('latin'); //talk

sayWin('кирилица'); //silence

sayWin('\ufeffкирилица'); //silence trying with BOM
```

Please, pay attention that you may have to install windows TTS voice package and select it as default system voice to play Cyrillic text(I done it previously).

Answer (score 1):

I may be answering too late, but let it stay here for the future.
I solved this problem for myself by first calling the command:

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding;
```

In your case, it will be something like

```
shell.addCommand('$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding');
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is transliteration Cyrillic text into Latin analog. It works but it far from expected results (words pronounces not as good as can be).

```
var transliterate = function(word) {
  var a = { "Ё": "YO", "Й": "I", "Ц": "TS", "У": "U", "К": "K", "Е": "E", "Н": "N", "Г": "G", "Ш": "SH", "Щ": "SCH", "З": "Z", "Х": "H", "Ъ": "'", "ё": "yo", "й": "i", "ц": "ts", "у": "u", "к": "k", "е": "e", "н": "n", "г": "g", "ш": "sh", "щ": "sch", "з": "z", "х": "h", "ъ": "'", "Ф": "F", "Ы": "I", "В": "V", "А": "a", "П": "P", "Р": "R", "О": "O", "Л": "L", "Д": "D", "Ж": "ZH", "Э": "E", "ф": "f", "ы": "i", "в": "v", "а": "a", "п": "p", "р": "r", "о": "o", "л": "l", "д": "d", "ж": "zh", "э": "e", "Я": "Ya", "Ч": "CH", "С": "S", "М": "M", "И": "yi", "Т": "T", "Ь": "'", "Б": "B", "Ю": "YU", "я": "ya", "ч": "ch", "с": "s", "м": "m", "и": "yi", "т": "t", "ь": "'", "б": "b", "ю": "yu" };
  return word.split('').map(function(char) {
    return a[char] || char;
  }).join("");
}

var sayWin = (text) => {

  text = /[а-яА-ЯЁё]/.test(text) ? transliterate(text) : text;

  var shell = new Shell({
    inputEncoding: 'binary'
  });
  shell.addCommand('Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech');
  shell.addCommand('$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer');
  shell.addCommand('$speak.Speak("' + text + '")');
  shell.on('output', data => {
    console.log("data", data);
  });
  shell.on('err', err => {
    console.log("err", err);
  });
  shell.on('end', code => {
    console.log("code", code);
  });
  return shell.invoke().then(output => {
    shell.dispose()
  });
}
```